# Making objects nonGlobal in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, scope

I have a function in JavaScript which looks something like this:

```
foo=function(listenerObject)
{
  a={count:0};
  foo2=function(){
    //does stuff with a
  }
  //register listenerObject to callback the function foo2
}
```

The problem is I end up using this function to register multiple listeners, but they all end up sharing the same 'a' object.  Is there a way to keep an object declaration inside a function from creeping into the global scope.
In other words I would like to prevent being able to do something like this

```
fun=function(){o={count:0}}
o.count++//o is now in the global scope
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). Really, you should be declaring *all* of your variables with `var` otherwise you'll, as you found out, get a bunch of global variables stepping on each other.

Example:

```
var foo = function(listenerObject) {
  var a = { count: 0 };
  ...
};
```